How to configure HLS in nixpkgs?
When using an older nixpkgs (2022), one can do the following to customize pkgs.haskellPackages.haskell-language-server to, for example, disable ormolu and fourmolu features:
    with pkgs.haskell.lib.compose; lib.flip lib.pipe [
      (disableCabalFlag "ormolu")
      (disableCabalFlag "fourmolu")
      (drv: drv.override { hls-ormolu-plugin = null; })
      (drv: drv.override { hls-fourmolu-plugin = null; })
    ];

How does one achieve the same on latest nixpkgs (nixpkgs-unstable)?
